# Getting SSLHandshakeException(Chain validation failed) on Android 9 after changing device date/time to future

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am getting the following exception on Android 9(and Android 8 too) after I change the device date/time setting to a future date that is more than 7 days from today:

```
    e = {SSLHandshakeException@5932} "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed"
 
    cause = {CertificateException@5938} "java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed"
 
    cause = {CertPathValidatorException@5947} "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date"
```

However, I do **not** get this exception if I change to a date that is within the 7 day period from today.

Also, I do **not** get this exception on tablet running on Android 5.